# Cannot contact dns server

Tags: router, dns

Just switched my isp, trying to figure out why my dvr and pos are not working properly, they both keep saying cannot contact dns server. I configured everything in my comcast modem to bypass and my third party router (linksys) to a static ip address and set the rules. what could the problem be?

Comment: if you locked down (static) the IP you can as easily lock in a few DNS ip addresses in the same general areas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

1. Contact your new ISP's tech support and have them help you correctly configure your modem/router which will include entering their DNS server addresses **(preferred)**, OR
2. Configure your modem/router to use publicly available DNS servers such as 8.8.8.8 (Google)